# heatmap-leaftet updating heatmap with more data

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I am using the heatmap.js library from pa7 in github successfully to make some heatmap
http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html

But when I updated the heatmap with additional data or new data points, the leaflet library does not really update with the additional data points.  There seems to be no method that can used for redraw.  I dont know if someone has already solved this problem, thats why I am asking to see.  Here is the simple portion of my additional script:

```
ndata=[{lat: 13.59, lon:-17.05, value: 11},{lat: 33.08, lon:-103.24, value: 19}]
testData.data.push.apply(ndata)
layer.addData(testData.data);
```

There is no errors in the console of Google chrome or no exceptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a `redraw` method in the layer:

```
var heatmapLayer = L.TileLayer.heatMap();
// add layer to map
heatmapLayer.redraw()
```

Having said this, in the latest version, the heatmap layer automatically redraws when you set the data (see https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/blob/d09c4e99852b4849e2b4d4f12976a9fce0327ca5/src/heatmap-leaflet.js#L112).